# Windows 10 shows french accents as Simplified Chinese characters

Tags: windows-10, fonts, language

I'm using Windows 10 with French set as the default language.
When I receive an email with French accents, often these letters will be misread as Simplified Chinese characters.
This is in the default mail client which comes with Windows 10 (simply called "Mail").

Edit: I just found a folder I downloaded with a french accent which was displayed as a Korean character. Therefore the problem is not limited to Mail, but is rather a Windows 10 issue. Still haven't found a setting to fix this.

For example:

> Merci de pr飩ser

I don't see any settings for changing the font I read messages in, or anything else which could fix the issue.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems related to special characters misinterpreted in Microsoft Outlook running in Windows 10. From this long Microsoft forum [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-chinese-characters-appearing-in/35d2d052-e1c3-4ba3-9563-ee471efce2e6) I understand that no straightforward solution exists.

In my case the problem was solved by stop using a "complex" signature in the email messages.

While not sure it applies to your problem I hope that the reading of the above link might help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this issue is occuring with French accents that I receive. This includes email messages in Mail, or downloaded folder or file names with French accents. So it's a bit different than just a Mail reply issue. It seems like an OS character encoding problem.